# React useEffect is not calling firebase read API after first load

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I'm making a todo app using react and firebase. I followed a tutorial from youtube to write the code.

Now I'm trying to add firebase. I'm using a `useEffect` hook to fetch data from firebase. It works on first render, but if I use other functionality like read, update it doesn't re-render. On refresh I get the result I wanted. If I add `todos` as a dependency to the `useEffect`, it works correctly but their are too many api calls.

App.jsx

```
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  console.log(input);

  // Create todo
  const createTodo = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    if (input === "") {
      alert("Please enter input");
      return;
    }
    await addDoc(collection(db, "react-todo"), {
      text: input,
      complete: false,
    });
    setInput("");
  };

  // Read todo from firebase
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTodos = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(collection(db, "react-todo"));
      let todoArray = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        todoArray.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      setTodos(todoArray);
    };
    getTodos();
  }, []);

  // update todo in firebase
  const toggleComplete = async (todo) => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "react-todo", todo.id), {
      complete: !todo.complete,
    });
  };

  // delete todo
  const deleteTodo = async (todo) => {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, "react-todo", todo.id));
  };

  return (
    <div className={style.bg}>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <h3 className={style.heading}>Todo App</h3>
        <form onSubmit={createTodo} className={style.form}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add Todo"
            className={style.input}
            value={input}
            onChangeCapture={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button className={style.button}>
            <AiOutlinePlus size={30} />
          </button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <Todo
              key={index}
              todo={todo}
              toggleComplete={toggleComplete}
              deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
        <p className={style.count}>{`You have ${todos.length} no. of todos`}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Todo.jsx

```
function Todo({ todo, toggleComplete, deleteTodo }) {
  return (
    <li className={todo.complete ? style.liComplete : style.li}>
      <div className={style.row}>
        <input
          onChange={() => toggleComplete(todo)}
          type="checkbox"
          checked={todo.complete ? "checked" : ""}
        />
        <p
          onClick={() => toggleComplete(todo)}
          className={todo.complete ? style.textComplete : style.text}
        >
          {todo.text}
        </p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo)}>{<FaRegTrashAlt />}</button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `todos` to your dependency array will create an infinite loop and is not the way to do it. As you said "there are too many api calls. This is because `setTodos` creates a new array each time it's called, which then causes the `useEffect` to run...which then calls `setTodos`, and so on.

Even though you call `getTodos` on first mount, react doesn't have any way of knowing that your database has updated when you call functions like `deleteTodo`. You need to manually refetch the data after each call. Something like this should work:

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  // Get todos
  const getTodos = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(collection(db, "react-todo"));
    let todoArray = [];
    data.forEach((doc) => {
      todoArray.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
    });
    setTodos(todoArray);
  };

  // Create todo
  const createTodo = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    if (input === "") {
      alert("Please enter input");
      return;
    }
    await addDoc(collection(db, "react-todo"), {
      text: input,
      complete: false,
    });
    setInput("");
    getTodos(); // REFETCH
  };

  // Read todo from firebase
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos(); // Initial fetch on first mount
  }, []);

  // update todo in firebase
  const toggleComplete = async (todo) => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "react-todo", todo.id), {
      complete: !todo.complete,
    });
    getTodos(); // REFETCH
  };

  // delete todo
  const deleteTodo = async (todo) => {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, "react-todo", todo.id));
    getTodos(); // REFETCH
  };

  return (
    <div className={style.bg}>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <h3 className={style.heading}>Todo App</h3>
        <form onSubmit={createTodo} className={style.form}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add Todo"
            className={style.input}
            value={input}
            onChangeCapture={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button className={style.button}>
            <AiOutlinePlus size={30} />
          </button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <Todo
              key={index}
              todo={todo}
              toggleComplete={toggleComplete}
              deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
        <p className={style.count}>{`You have ${todos.length} no. of todos`}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. App working the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid an API call on every action so you should update your `todos` locally manipulating data you've changed:

```
const createTodo = async (newTodo) => {
  ... handle db logic
    
  setTodos((current) => ([
    ...current,
    newTodo
  ]))
};

const toggleComplete = async (todo) => {
  ... handle your db logic

  setTodos((currents) => currents.map(current => {
    if(current.id !== todo.id) return current

    return {
      ...todo,
      complete: !todo.complete
    }
  }))
};

const deleteTodo = async (todo) => {
  .... handle your db logic

  setTodos((currents) => currents.filter(current => current.id !== todo.id))
};
```

Only make sure your data was saved successfully and now you can just update what user see locally. Hope this helps

Comment: Assuming api calls are successful isn't usually best practice as it can lead to errors in what you're showing your user vs what is actually on the db.

Comment: @sallf I see no difference between fetching data again from database and updating data locally as the API call has finished without errors. In this case, if you successfully deleted a TODO you don't need to read all your database again because deletion API call was successfully. If it had an error then refetching is a good idea. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I hear what you're saying -- though I wouldn't have interpreted "API call has finished without errors" from `...handle your db logic` . One use case would be if multiple people are editing the db. Syncing after each api call would definitely be better practice , but that's above and beyond what this question is asking.